# Add Metadata on Amazon S3 object is not persistent

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, metadata

I am trying to add a new meta data information  to an S3 object so I know what are all objects that I already processed. But for some reason, the new data that I added is not persistent. When I exit the program, its not there anymore. I do not see the new field "processed"  in the old data, but I see it is present in the new data. I expect the newly added metadata field to present on the object permanently but it is gone after I exit the program

```
        ObjectMetadata objMetaData = new ObjectMetadata();
        objMetaData = s3.getObjectMetadata(bucketName,prefix);
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Map<String, String> newMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map = objMetaData.getUserMetadata();
        System.out.println("old Meta data is " + map.toString());
        objMetaData.addUserMetadata("x-amz-meta-processed", "true");
        newMap = objMetaData.getUserMetadata();
        System.out.println("New processed data  is" +newMap.toString());
```

Comment: You appear to only alter the metadata locally, so why is that a surprise?

Comment: so do I have to do putObject again for this new meta data to take place?  I thought addUserMetadata should automatically add the new data without having to put the whole object again just to add some piece of usermetadata.  Please clarify if i am getting this wrong.

Comment: Well is there an `s3.setObjectMetadata`?

Comment: yes, but it resets the whole metadata to just the new field that I add. Then I lose all the existing metadata items already present on the object.

Comment: So call it with *the whole of the updated metadata*, or see if there's a method that updates rather than replaces. Are you expecting me to drop in and type it for you or something? **Put some effort in**.

Comment: Thanks John, I should be able to add the whole data along with new field. Thought if someone has a better technique than having to repeat what is already there. I did put some effort for sure before posting this. Thanks for  the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your confusion comes from not understanding an important part of the design of S3:

- S3 objects can't be modified, and neither can their metadata.  It's all immutable.

Wait, what?  It's technically true.

> The only way to modify object metadata is to make a copy of the object and set the metadata.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html

You can, in practice, "add" metadata to an object, but what that *really* means is that you're asking S3 to make a copy of the object, with the same key for the source and target, but using "different" metadata.

If the "different" metadata you want on the object includes metadata that was already present, you have to include that in the request.

S3 supports copying an object onto itself, so you don't actually have to re-upload the object.

What you are doing now is just changing the values in your local code's data structures.